# Using QuantLib to build Flat Forward Curve using Changes assumed from central bank meetings to price FRAs

Tags: quantlib, pricing, libor

What I am trying to do is price EURIBOR6M FRAs using a curve built in quantlib with changes in rate due to central bank meetings.

For concreteness, my goal is to price EURIBOR6M FRAs, say 1x7 FRA, given changes from the meetings. Assume the following details:

```
meeting_dates = [
    dt.date(2024, 3, 7),
    dt.date(2024, 4, 11),
    dt.date(2024, 6, 6),
    dt.date(2024, 7, 18),
    dt.date(2024, 9, 12),
    dt.date(2024, 10, 17),
    dt.date(2024, 12, 12)
]

rate_change = [-0.6, -5.7, -18.4, -14.6, -18.6, -17.8, -22.8]

curve_date = dt.date(2024, 1, 8)

euribor6m_rate = 3.929

estr_rate = 3.904
```

Given these how I do build the flat forward curve in quantlib, then price the 1x7 FRA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have enough information. You need the ESTR/6MEuribor basis to do this properly.

You can start by creating an ESTR curve from your policy meeting steps:

(For a Quantlib - Rateslib conversion review here: https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/z_quantlib.html)

```python
from rateslib import *

m = [
    dt(2024, 1, 8),
    dt(2024, 3, 7),
    dt(2024, 4, 11),
    dt(2024, 6, 6),
    dt(2024, 7, 18),
    dt(2024, 9, 12),
    dt(2024, 10, 17),
    dt(2024, 12, 12),
]
curve = Curve(
    nodes={
        dt(2024, 1, 8):1.0,
        dt(2024, 3, 7):1.0,
        dt(2024, 4, 11):1.0,
        dt(2024, 6, 6):1.0,
        dt(2024, 7, 18):1.0,
        dt(2024, 9, 12):1.0,
        dt(2024, 10, 17):1.0,
        dt(2024, 12, 12):1.0,
        dt(2025, 1, 31):1.0
    },
    convention="act360",
    calendar="tgt"
)
solver = Solver(
    curves=[curve],
    instruments=[
        IRS(m[0], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve),
        Spread(IRS(m[0], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve),
               IRS(m[1], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve)),
        Spread(IRS(m[1], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve),
               IRS(m[2], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve)),
        Spread(IRS(m[2], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve),
               IRS(m[3], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve)),
        Spread(IRS(m[3], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve),
               IRS(m[4], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve)),
        Spread(IRS(m[4], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve),
               IRS(m[5], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve)),
        Spread(IRS(m[5], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve),
               IRS(m[6], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve)),
        Spread(IRS(m[6], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve),
               IRS(m[7], "1b", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve)),
    ],
    s=[3.90, -1, -7.5, -19.8, -16.7, -20, -18.2, -23.2]
)
curve.plot("1b")
```

[image]

Then you can add a spread curve on top of this, suppose the ESTR/6M spread is linearly interpolated between the IMM dates:

```
spread_curve = Curve(
    nodes={
        dt(2024, 1, 8): 1.0,
        dt(2024, 3, 20): 1.0,
        dt(2024, 6, 19): 1.0,
        dt(2024, 9, 18): 1.0,
        dt(2024, 12, 19): 1.0,
    },
    convention="act360",
    calendar="tgt"
)
curve_6m_composite = CompositeCurve([curve, spread_curve])
solver2 = Solver(
    pre_solvers=[solver],
    curves=[curve_6m_composite, spread_curve],
    instruments=[
        IRS(dt(2024, 1, 8), "6m", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve_6m_composite),
        IRS(dt(2024, 3, 20), "6m", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve_6m_composite),
        IRS(dt(2024, 6, 19), "6m", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve_6m_composite),
        IRS(dt(2024, 9, 18), "6m", spec="eur_irs", curves=curve_6m_composite),
    ],
    s=[3.925, 3.88, 3.5725, 3.2125]
)
curve_6m_composite.plot("6m", comparators=[curve], labels=["6M Euribor", "6M ESTR"])
```

[image]

These images are too large a scale to highlight what this is doing, but if your compare this 6m curve to one that has just linearly interpolation of 6m rate between depo and IMM rates, you will observes a few basis points of difference in the intervening months.

Comment: Thank you! rateslib is really intuitive! What does the "1b" mean when you input it into the IRS and Spread functions? i assume it's a 1d tenor? I've tried looking but could not find a glossary 


I understand you really need a basis, but I was wondering whether you can start with the euribor6m rate and directly build the 6m euribor curve given the changes from meeting dates?

Comment: No you cant do that because there is a basis element that has to be priced in, unless you assume the basis is constant in which case it is essentially the same as above.

Comment: suppose on 2024-01-28  the EUR BASIS SWAP 3v6 IMM1 is 9.0 and EUR FRA-ESTR Spread 3M I is 5.4 how can i incorporate these to get the ESTR/6M spread