# Explicit pythonic building of Flat Forward Curve using Changes assumed from central bank meetings to price FRAs

Tags: pricing, modeling, libor, forward-curve

This question is related to the following questions asked previously, primarily the first:

[Using QuantLib to build Flat Forward Curve using Changes assumed from central bank meetings to price FRAs](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/78519/using-quantlib-to-build-flat-forward-curve-using-changes-assumed-from-central-ba)

[Explicit step by step curve construction using FRAs](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/78348/explicit-step-by-step-curve-construction-using-fras)

My objectives are:

1. I am trying to do is price EURIBOR6M FRAs with a curve due to changes in rate on central bank meetings.
2. Understand and explicitly do this step-by-step
3. Find the optimal changes in rate which reproduce price of FRAs as quoted in the market

Thanks to @Attack68, his excellent book and answers I have understood a lot.

To achieve my goals I am implementing an explicit pythonic solution without the use of quantlib or (the excellent pkg) rateslib.

I have two approaches I want to implement and compare:

**Approach 1**

1. Build the ESTR Curve from the policy meeting steps
2. Build basis curve using the ESTR/6MEuribor basis
3. Price FRAs using combined curve. The pricing of a 1x7 FRA is simply using the discount formula for forwards interpolating the appropriate discount factors from the combined curve. Here I choose log linear interpolation.
4. (Objective 3) Write an optimisation algorithm to calculate what changes in rate is required to reproduce market quoted FRAs

**Approach 2**

1. Given the ESTR rate today (curve date) and a 'scenario':= the changes in rates on meeting dates one can model the ON rate for dates between meeting dates (assuming ON rate is the same i.e. flat)
2. To price the FRA is to calculate the implied rate by compounding the ON rate over the accrual period of the FRA, annualising that rate and adding the basis (assuming flat basis). My attempt of just function is:

```
def calculate_projected_annual_ON_rate_over_accrual_period(current_index_rate: float, scenario: pd.DataFrame, accrual_period: tuple, basis: float):
    # Generate all dates within the accrual period
    all_dates = pd.date_range(start=accrual_period[0], end=accrual_period[1], freq='D')
    all_dates = np.array([d.date() for d in all_dates])
    # Initialize rates array with the initial rate
    annual_ON_rates = np.full(len(all_dates), current_index_rate)
    
    # Convert meeting_dates and fixing_dates to numpy arrays
    meeting_dates_np = scenario['meeting_dates'].values
    rate_change_np = scenario['rate_change'].values
    fixing_dates_np = scenario['fixing_dates'].values
    fixing_dates_next_day = [ql.Date.to_date( ql.Date.from_date(d) + ql.Period("1d") ) for d in fixing_dates_np ]
    
    # Calculate rate changes for each day based on meeting dates
    for i, meeting_date in enumerate(fixing_dates_next_day):
        mask = (all_dates >= meeting_date)  # Mask for dates after the current meeting date
        annual_ON_rates[mask] = current_index_rate + rate_change_np[i] / 100
    dcf = (accrual_period[1] - accrual_period[0]).days / 365
    days_compounded_for = np.array([3 if date.weekday() == 4 else 0 if date.weekday() >= 5 else 1 for date in all_dates])
    daily_rates = 1 + (days_compounded_for*annual_ON_rates/100)/365
    implied_rate = (np.prod(daily_rates) - 1)/dcf * 100 
    return implied_rate + basis
```

**Questions**

1. How do implement approach 1 in a systematic pythonic manner?
2. Are my approaches valid and sound, independently, and/or valid to compare to each other?
3. I dont have ESTR/EURIBOR6M basis but I have 3M FRA-ESTR spread and EUR BASIS SWAP 3x6 IMM1 (bbg ticker = EUBCF1 ICPL Curncy). How can I use these to calculate the basis of ESTR/EUribor6M ?

Assume the following data:

```
scenario = {
'meeting_dates': {0: datetime.date(2024, 3, 7),
  1: datetime.date(2024, 4, 11),
  2: datetime.date(2024, 6, 6),
  3: datetime.date(2024, 7, 18),
  4: datetime.date(2024, 9, 12),
  5: datetime.date(2024, 10, 17),
  6: datetime.date(2024, 12, 12)},
 'rate_change': {0: -0.3,
  1: -6.3,
  2: -18.7,
  3: -15.2,
  4: -19.2,
  5: -15.8,
  6: -17.7},
 'fixing_dates': {0: datetime.date(2024, 3, 13),
  1: datetime.date(2024, 4, 17),
  2: datetime.date(2024, 6, 12),
  3: datetime.date(2024, 7, 24),
  4: datetime.date(2024, 9, 18),
  5: datetime.date(2024, 10, 23),
  6: datetime.date(2024, 12, 18)}
}

curve_date = dt.date(2024, 2, 28)
estr_rate = 3.906
fra_estr_3m_spread = 5.4
basis_swap_3v6 = 9.0
```